# ViewerJS: is it possible to disable buttons?

Tags: javascript

I'm using [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org) to display PDF files inline on a web page. If the iframe becomes too narrow however, some of the buttons and captions become unreadable like so:

[image]

Is it possible to disable the buttons? I only need the fullscreen one anyway. Looking at the ViewerJS code I have no idea where to start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very much depending on where you load your iframe content from. if it is from he same domain, then you have direct access to its content.

For example, open the link that you've linked as an example and in browser console execute the following command:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementById('presentation').style.display='none';
```

Look at the first iframe button row carefully :)

Comment: Yeah the plugin sits in a subfolder on my server. Nice solution :) So to do this programatically, I just put the script to disable all buttons at the end of the page that contains the iframes and then I'm safe?

Comment: that is one approach - yes. You just have to inspect the content to find correct ids to hide. and you have to make sure that content is loaded when you hide them.